# Check for SQL Empty strings in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamapper

I'm wondering how I can check for Empty SQL strings in Ruby on rails, since checking if nil do not work if empty and checking if it's = "" do not work either.

```
          <% if @model.option4 != nil or @poll.option4 != "" %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
               <p>POST STUFF ABOUT IT</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
```

It works perfect to check if it's nil but not when checking if empty. Is there another way to check this? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I'm using DataMapper and SQLite to handle the database. Not ActiveRecord.

```
      Model.create(question: params["question"],
      option1: params["option1"],
      option2: params["option2"],
      option3: params["option3"],
      option4: params["option4"],
      option5: params["option5"],
      created_on: Time.now,
      user: @user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<% unless @model.option4.blank? %>
```

In your code you most likely misused `or` when you needed `and`. However using `blank?` or `present?` methods is a common rails way to handle both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your help, all tho .blank? dont works for me.
"undefined method `blank?'"
<% unless @model.option4.blank? %>

Comment: You had right with the and/or misuse. Works great with "and".
I dont really understand why tho... with "and" it sounds more like option4 should be both nil and empty...

Anyways, it seems to work, thank you! :)

Comment: @user1945911 - With `or` you execute it when it is not nil or not empty - since it can't be nil and empty at the same time it is always true. In general, you missed de morgan's law: `!(a && b) == !a || !b`